# Limit of a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n = \frac{1+a_{n-1}x^n }{a_{n-1} + x^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For a problem I want to solve this, but after trying all the methods I could find, I did not succeed. Can anyone help? Thanks!
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\quad\text{where}\quad a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}\cdot x^n + 1}{a_{n-1} + x^n}
$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempts, even if they all failed. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: The result $\coth(x+y)=(\coth x\coth y+1)(\coth x+\coth y)$ may help you.

Comment: 1 or -1, consider about the (a_n) - 1.

Answer (score 1):

1. To begin with, if $x=1$ then $a_k=1$ for all $k\geq 1$.
2. On the other hand, if $x=-1$ then $a_2=1$ (for the same reason), and $a_3$ isn't well-defined (division by $1+(-1)^3=0$).
3. We now consider the case $|x|>1$. We make use of the [hyperbolic cotangent function](http://www.librow.com/articles/article-11/appendix-a-19) as proposed in the above comment of @Somos. For all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ the fact that $|x^n|>1$ allows to define $y_n:= \mathrm{arcoth}(x^n)$. When $|a_{n-1}|>1$ we similarly define $b_{n-1}:= \mathrm{arcoth}(a_{n-1})$, so that
   $$ a_n = \frac {a_{n-1} x^n + 1} {a_{n-1} +x_n} = \frac {\coth(b_{n-1})\coth(y_n) + 1} {\coth(b_{n-1}) + \coth(y_n)} = \coth(b_{n-1} + y_n).$$
   This proves $|a_k|>1$ for all $k\geq n-1$ by induction, along with $b_n = b_{n-1} + y_n$ and
   $$ b_k = b_{n-1} + \sum_{i=n}^k y_i = \mathrm{arcoth}(a_{n-1}) + \sum_{i=n}^k \mathrm{arcoth}(x^i).$$
   The series is increasing and thus $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has an unattained limit in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ (which we can prove to be real actually, using that $\mathrm{arcoth}(x)\sim 1/x$ when $x\to +\infty$, see the explicit expression of the [arc-hyperbolic cotangent function](http://www.librow.com/articles/article-11/appendix-a-10)). This proves that the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.

Note that when well-defined, the sequence $c_n=1/a_n$ verifies the same recursive formula as $a_n$ and we can consider this sequence when $|a_{n-1}|<1$ and $a_{n-1}a_n\neq 0$ (a property which is conserved by the above induction).

As a remark, $a_{n-1}=0$ for some $n$ implies $a_n = 1/x^n \neq 0$ and $a_{n+1}=x^n(x+1)/(x^{2n+1}+1) \neq 0$.

*The case $a_{n-1}\in\{-1, 1\}$ is trivial since it implies that the sequence is constant for $k\geq n-1$.*

4. The only remaining case is $|x|<1$. One could be tempted to simplify the recursive formula by $x^n$ or by $a_{n-1} x^n$ in order to use the previous case $|x|<1$. The issue is that those simplifications provide, respectively,
   $$ a_n =  \frac {a_{n-1} + (1/x)^n} {a_{n-1}(1/x)^n+1} \quad\mbox{and}\quad c_n = \frac {c_{n-1} + (1/x)^n} {c_{n-1}(1/x)^n+1}.$$
   This is not exactly the same recursive formula since the fraction is inversed.
   Indeed, when $x^n\to 0$ the limit formula is $a_n=1/a_{n-1}$ (whereas it was $a_n = a_{n-1}$ in the case $|x|>1$ if the sequence is bounded). Therefore, it makes more sense to consider a recursive dependence of order $2$. Some computation yields for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$:
   $$ a_{n+1} = \frac {a_{n-1} d_n + 1} {a_{n-1} + d_n} \quad\mbox{with}\quad d_n = \frac {1+x^{2n+1}} {x^n+x^{n+1}}>1.$$
   *The function $f_n$ such that $d_n=f_n(x)$ is indeed decreasing on $]-1; 1[$ with $f_n(1)=1$, one can prove it by differentiating for instance.*
   This allows to proceed as in the case $|x|>1$.
   The limit is the same (with $x^{-1}$ in the sum instead of $x$) noting that
   $$ d_n = \frac {1+x^{-(2n+1)}} {x^{-(n+1)} + x^{-n}} \quad\mbox{and}\quad \mbox{arcoth}(d_n) = y_{-n} + y_{-(n+1)}, $$
   and recalling that the dependence is of order $2$.

Comment: +1 (though according to the rules of this site, such a "low-quality question" shouldn't be answered). Please, can you elaborate in your post on the finiteness of $\lim b_n$ when $|x|>1$?

Comment: I don't see why this limit is a "low-quality question", I've personnally upvoted it (the answer shows how non-trivial it is).

Comment: The equivalent $\mathrm{arcoth}(x)\sim 1/x$ is not complicated to prove using the logarithm expression in the link I provide, and the sum of $1/x^i$ converges when $|x|>1$.

Comment: It is "low-quality" for lack of "context" (mainly: attempts), as the closure banner explains. On this site, it is not sufficient for a question to be interesting for it to be "good-quality". Thank you for the explanation, I was to lazy to realize how the equivalent was used.